# Assign coach to members automatically

Tags: php, crm

I'm creating a CRM where I want to assign coaches to members on signup. I'm struggling to find a logic for the below scenarios.

1) At the moment we have 50 users and 5 coaches.
2) We want to assign coach 1st to user 1st, coach 2nd to user 2nd and so on.
3) Coach 1st will then assigned to user 6th. By using this approach each coach will get equal users.

I'm using below code to achieve it, it works for me, but I don't know how reliable is this.

```
  static function getACoach($userId) {
    $totalCoach = 5;
    if($userId > $totalCoach) {
        $coachId = $userId % $totalCoach;
    } else {
        $coachId = $userId;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: please show us your best attempt(relevant code), so we can help you on your way

Comment: Hi @lovelace, thanks for your reply. I added my code and it is working. Not sure if it is stable enough

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/mnito/round-robin

Comment: Hi @RaminRezazadeh, thanks for the reply. My code is concise and it is working in all possible scenarios. I'm still testing it. Maybe I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple approach worked for me.

```
function getACoach($userId) {
   $totalCoach = 5;
   if($userId > $totalCoach) {
      $coachId = $userId % $totalCoach;
   } else {
    $coachId = $userId;
   }
   return $coachId;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the logic is correct [your code](https://3v4l.org/5KLvm) shows sequence output that does not seem correct... `coachId 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0...`